# Recordset (classic asp) storing empty values after executing SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have restored a database from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2014. I am trying to execute a stored procedure from a classic ASP application.

After execution, the recordset stores a few column values as empty and a few columns with proper values. If I execute the the stored procedure in DB, it works fine, I get the correct values for all the columns.

While debugging, I quick watch those columns which get empty values and found that Actual Size is set to -1.

Why is it showing Actual size = -1 ? Is there any column data type compatibility issue between 2005 and 2014 ? E.g. I have datatypes such as `varchar(max)`, `shortdatetime` etc.

```
Set ObjRs = ObjConn.Execute("lp_view " & id)
ORD = ReadDate(ObjRs("Date"))
Addr = (ObjRs("address"))
```

Both ORD and Addr = empty. The column Date & address have some values in the database.

[image]

Comment: id =1. Other columns are getting their values, but few are getting empty. Id is value is coming correctly in Set command

Comment: Size = -1 is a placeholder for the `varchar(max)` datatypes, since those can hold up to 2 GB of data.

Comment: Try ObjRs.MoveNext() before reading, maybe there's some extra record in there with blank values.

Comment: @marc_s Actual Size =-1 is showing for smalldatetime as well.. Interesting thing is that , i have few more smalldatetime  columns, where i am getting data and Acutal size is not -1 there.

Comment: Yes, there are big differences between a 2005 and 2014 SQL Server database. If you are still using the old SQLOLEDB provider for your database connection expect more issues.

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks.. I found the solution. I have changed the Table's Data type to varchar(8000) instead of varchar(max).  But i wasn't happy with the solution. So I altered the connection string and revert data type to varchar(max) & It works .